# Standard Unicode symbols for logic operations

Tags: logic, notation

There are [these](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Logic_gates_unified_symbols) logic gates symbols, but I am looking for the more low-level math-like symbols such as those found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols), but for all the logic operations. There doesn't seem to be a central place for them, but [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) seem close.

I would like to know if from your perspective [those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) are the standard symbols, or if there are others.

```
AND ∧
OR ∨
XOR ⊻
XNOR ↔
NAND ↑
NOR ↓
NOT ¬
```

These are the only two that seem standard:

```
AND ∧
OR ∨
```

I'm not sure about the other ones, if there is a preferred set of symbols, or ones that are used most often in papers and the like.

Comment: They are all standard, and easily invoked in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: The table for gates isn't entirely correct, it is quite common to make, for example, a Nor gate by putting circles on the inputs of an And gate, that is in fact the whole point of the symbolic notation.

Comment: Yes, these are relatively standard; you may also see $\barwedge$ and $\overline{\vee}$ for NAND and NOR, and $\oplus$ and $\overline{\oplus}$ for XOR and XNOR.

Comment: The *de facto* standard for papers is to use $\LaTeX$ (often together with packages like $\mathtt{amssymb}$). If you use $\LaTeX$, you don't need to know about Unicode.
[MathML](https://www.w3.org/Math/) defines a standard for mathematical content on the Web and includes definitions of a standard set of XML entities for mathematics and associated Unicode code points. [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/mathjax.html) which is used to enter and render mathematics on MSE uses MathML (and the $\LaTeX$ interface supports a useful subset of the MathML entities).